# Why did they show Tennessee a snowy state?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3*, Tony Stark went to Tennessee to investigate the strange death of a woman there.

The state was shown covered with snow, like that's Montana!

According to [this site](http://www.usa.com/rank/us--average-snow--state-rank.htm), Tennessee is in the place of 41st out of 50+1 states in the aspect of getting snow.

Also, I remember a quote from Luis, Scott Lang's best friend from *Ant-Man and the Wasp*:

> *We live in California, not Minnesota!*

And California is just two below Tennessee in that website.

Comment: I have read that Tennesee has a semi tropical climate and thus is a good place for an elephant sancturary.  But Tennesse also has seasons including winter, as well as mountains in places, and mountains get snow.  Another semi tropical location is Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, which also sometimes gets snow in the winter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does snow in Tennessee, the eastern part of the state gets the most. In 2016 Nashville got 8 inches in one day.

Comment: I didn't say the state is completely dry

Comment: Tony landed in Rose Hill, TN there are 2 in Tennessee. One is in the western part of the state the other in Union County northeast of Knoxville which gets about 7 inches of snow per year. So it is very possible to have landed in snow. Don't forget the Marvel universe is fictional.